# Stripe auth and capture in javascript

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe supports two-step payment flow for authorizing and capturing money on cards. For that we have to send a capture = false parameter.

My question is how do i send this parameter in javascript api??

```
var args = {
    number: jQuery('#AccountNumber').val(),
    exp_month: jQuery('#ExpirationMonth').val(),
    exp_year: jQuery('#ExpirationYear').val(),
    address_line1: jQuery('#baddress1').val(),
    address_line2: jQuery('#baddress2').val(),
    address_city: jQuery('#bcity').val(),
    address_state: jQuery('#bstate').val(),
    address_zip: jQuery('#bzipcode').val(),
    address_country: jQuery('#bcountry').val()
};



//create token
Stripe.createToken(args, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical payment flow with Stripe can be divided in two steps:

1. Client-side, in your frontend (HTML + Javascript) code, you collect the customer's payment information using Stripe's prebuilt [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) form, or your own custom form with the [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) library. This will return a token that you then send to your server.
2. Server-side, in your backend code (in PHP, Python, Ruby, or whichever server-side programming language you prefer), you use the token in a [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to actually charge the card.

If you want to use the ["auth & capture"](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture) flow, you need to pass the [`capture=false`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-capture) parameter in the charge creation request, i.e. in your server-side code, not in the token creation step.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Stripe.createToken(args, stripeResponseHandler);` with

```
Stripe.card.createToken(args, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Now your `stripeResponseHandler` is a Javascript function that is executed once a response is received from Stripe's servers after capturing the credit card details. So you would need some sort of code to process the response:

```
 function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();

  }
}
```

For more information: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-card-details